# supporting fullscreen cell in both iPhone screen sizes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have an app set up that has a gallery, I am pushing to a collection view with the cell set up full screen with an image in, the problem I have is... If I set my cell size as 320 x 416 (iPhone 4/4S fullscreen with Nav Bar) when I use the iPhone 5 simulator I have gaps top and bottom. If I set the cells size as 320 x 504 (iPhone 5 fullscreen with Nav Bar) then if I use an iPhone4/4S the image doesn't show as the cell is out of bounds.

Is there a way round this? Also is there a way of changing this in a universal app for the iPad a s well or is it best to remake the app for iPad as a separate thing?

Thanks

Seems to be some confusion on this so let me try and make this clearer... I have an app with a gallery and a search, the search is from a table view pushing to a standard detail view and the image view here resizes, happy days. With my gallery I have this as two collection view, one with a grid and one with a cell sized to the screen size so I can horizontally scroll through the images. It is this that I want to size according to the screen used.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try like this.

Either set the itemSize property.

```
 layout.itemSize = self.view.bounds.size;
```

Or use the delegate method

```
  - (CGSize)collectionView:(PSUICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(PSUICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
    return self.view.bounds.size;
  }
```

You can make some adjustment in the values. Anyway it should be depends on the views size. Like that it will be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your app in letterbox environment in iPhone 5 . So add **Default-568h@2x.png** in your project to run it in full screen in iPhone 5 too.

Comment: I already have that, I'm not taking about the loading screen I mean in the actual app itself I have a gallery with a collection view of images, click on an image and it segues to another collection view full screen. It's how to get that to work full screen universally I'm stuck with.

Comment: By adding the default-568h@2x image you ARE enabling the fullscreen mode. You will need to write your app to make sure it is using this full screen though.

Comment: ok sorry let me get my head around this, where do I need to add the default-568h@2x? because as far as I was aware this is the loading screen image and nothing to do with collection view autoresizing???

Comment: Copy this image in launch image section for Retina(4-inch)  in your project summary section.

Comment: ok let me try and make this clearer... I have an app with a gallery and a search, the search is from a table view pushing to a standard detail view and the image view here resizes, happy days. With my gallery I have this as two collection view, one with a grid and one with a cell sized to the screen size so I can horizontally scroll through the images. It is this that I want to size according to the screen used.